# Functions as a Power Series

Tags: functions, power-series

So, say you had $\dfrac{(-4)^n}{-4}$

Would that be equivalent to $(-1)^{n-1} \times 4^{n-1}$? If so, how come it isn't $1^{n-1}$ (or just $1$) ?

Comment: What does it have to do with power series?

Comment: @Vim Point well taken, but perhaps the OP is practicing with the ratio test, where these algebraic manipulations occur frequently

Comment: It was a question from a chapter with power series, @imranfat is correct, I just didn't include the whole question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the formulas: $(ab)^{n-1} = a^{n-1}b^{n-1}, a = -1, b = 4, \dfrac{x^n}{x} = x^{n-1}$ with $x = -4$ you have: $\dfrac{(-4)^n}{-4} = (-4)^{n-1} = (-1)^{n-1}\times 4^{n-1}$